What desktop video player allows fluid backward seeking?
I just discovered that the stock video player on my Android phone allows me to do smooth (24fps) seeking by dragging the seek cursor. It works perfectly for studying details about dance patterns from a recording, as opposed to seeking back to play a 4-second section repeatedly, which is always approximate. Dragging allows going over the exact part I want repeatedly.
I've tried this with VLC and MPC-HC on Windows but the scrolling is choppy and it achieves 4 fps at best. Seeking is still choppy after adjusting "Small backward seek" to 200ms in MPC-HC.
Is there a desktop player and/or some setting that can be adjusted to enable smooth rewind and forward like the Android player ?
